# CSS selector syntax: *, ::before, ::after {}

Tags: html, css

```css
*, ::before, ::after {}
```

What odes this syntax do exactly ?

If there is no argument before `::before` and `::after`, do they refer to `*` in this case ? Or is `::before`  and `::after` syntax without the argument in front doing something specific by itself ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If there is no argument before ::before and ::after, do they refer to * in this case ?

*Effectively* yes.

The [universal selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors) matches any element and has no influence on [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) so it can be implicitly considered to be part of any selector.